# how to Access identity user id which is implemented in class library from other mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Background:

Identity is implemented in one class library and trying to get the Id field from identity class library to mvc application.I am able get the user id in class library in which identity is implemented but not getting any solution to access it in another mvc appliction.

question:How to access ID from Identity's AspNetUsers table to mvc aplication?

Answer (score 0):

Implement custom ApplicationUser based on IdentityUser, use your own table to store users (instead of build-in membership tables), override UserStore with your own one and you will have access to everything.